# No CLR runtime found error after calling dumpheap -stat

Tags: .net-core, runtime-error, runtime, dump, coreclr

[image]ERROR: No CLR runtime found. This means that a .NET runtime module or the DAC for the runtime can not be found or downloaded.

Hello when I try to analyze memory dump of a running process:

I run following commands on windows terminal>
 `dotnet-dump analyze  C:\Users\Admin\dump_20231108_113908.dmp` and
`dumpheap -stat`

Comment: hey, did you find out why this was happening, i am getting the same error and cant seem to figure out what's going on.

Comment: No I havent found anything yet :(

Answer (score 0):

I got this exact error because my dump was a 64bit dump of a 32bit process.

In my case, the process was `c:\windows\syswow64\w3wp.exe` (i.e. 32bit IIS running on 64bit Windows).

The fix was to take the dump from a 32bit process: close any existing Task Manager instances, run `c:\windows\syswow64\taskmgr.exe`, and use that to take the dump. This fixed the issue for me.